Missing shared groups in Passwords app on macOS
Since macOS Sequoia, I am missing the shared password groups in the Passwords app. It worked fine in Sonoma.

iCloud Keychain is enabled and the syncing of other passwords works fine.
iPhone and iPad on the same Apple Account with iCloud Keychain enabled show shared groups fine and sync changes correctly.
In Safari, passwords in a shared group do show correctly and can be autofilled, so they're definitely present!
The Passwords app is missing the ability to create groups too, let alone see existing groups.
Share passwords or passkeys with people you trust on Mac - Passwords User Guide says


Choose File > New Shared Group.


but this option is missing for me.

I have tried deleting ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Passwords and ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Passwords.plist to no avail.
How can I access my shared password groups in the Passwords app on macOS?

Do you have an iPhone or iPad on the same Apple Account, and if so, does it have the same problem?

@LincDavis Yes the iPhone and iPad are both fine showing and syncing changes in the shared groups. Thanks I'll pop that detail in the question.

just wanted to chip in, and say I'm having a similar issue, they were there, then disappeared, randomly appeared again later (perhaps after 15.1 update), and have just noticed they are gone again today have the same account on iPhone, and iPhone is fine

Same issue here. I tried deactivating/reactivating iCloud password sync, it didn't help.

defaults write com.apple.Safari WBSOngoingCredentialSharing 1

Relaunch Passwords to take effect. Set to 0 to disable again. No need to have Safari running.
Why does Passwords read Safari settings? I have no idea. There are no results for "WBSOngoingCredentialSharing" on Google at the time of writing.

Undocumented secret handshakes will be the downfall of us…

I have the same issue, and setting 'WBSOngoingCredentialSharing' didn't have any effect.

If anyone still has this problem, this is what worked for me:
I created a new shared group on my Mac, it was missing at the top, had to hover the "shared groups" label in the app and press the plus, e.g. Test, then took my iPhone and moved one of my passwords from another shared group in the test group I just created on my Mac. After that it took a minute and then it started to sync the shared groups.

Unfortunately in my case the option to create a new shared password group is missing on macOS as discussed, and creating a new one on iOS for it to sync did not help.

it was missing for me as well, at least at the top, hovering the shared groups tab and pressing the plus worked.

Interesting, I'm not sure what tab you mean, I think a screenshot could be useful?
